# How to dynamically create a nested tree with depth 10 in JavaScript using a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, tree, nested

I have a general tree class with: myTree = new Tree(string), appendChildNode(node), createChildNode(string), myTree.print() functions and myTree.name, myTree.children, etc attributes.

I know, I can create a tree depth (10) by hand like so:

```
// declare new tree
myTree = new Tree('Diagrams')
// adding nodes by hand here    
myTree.createChildNode('A1').createChildNode('A2').createChildNode('A3').createChildNode('A4').createChildNode('A5').createChildNode('A6').createChildNode('A7').createChildNode('A8').createChildNode('A9').createChildNode('A10')
myTree.print()
```

**How would I do that programmatically using a for loop?** Expected result depth 10:

```
Diagrams
 A1
  A2
   A3
    A4
     A5
      A6
       A7
        A8
         A9
          A10
```

Sorry, if this is a question that was answered before, I just cannot come up with a proper query to search for a solution to this. I think I am missing a syntax in JS for doing that. Info: I took the following general tree implementation: https://github.com/beforesemicolon/tutorials-files/blob/master/tree-generic.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop, adding child to a node, and updating node to be the child and so on. Tested :-)

```js
var myTree = new Tree('Diagrams')
var node = myTree;
var children = 'A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,A10'.split(",");
children.forEach(function(child) {
  node = node.createChildNode(child)
})
myTree.print()

function Tree(tree_name) {
  var children = [];
  var name = tree_name
  this.createChildNode = function(child_name) {
    var child = new Tree(child_name);
    children.push(child)
    return child;
  }
  this.print = function(level) {
    level = level || 0;
    var space = ' '.repeat(level)
    console.log(space + name)
    children.forEach(function(child) {
      child.print(level + 1);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: `"message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'",`

Comment: `"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: Tree is not defined",`

Answer (score 1):

```
let tree = new Tree("Diagrams"); // create the tree
let node = tree; // we need this variable so we can assign the current node to it in the loop

for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let name = "A" + (i + 1); // the name of the current node
  node = node.createChildNode(name); // create the node with the given name and assign the newly created node so we can create the sub node in the next iteration
}
```

*not tested*

Comment: Thanks Michael. Do I get it right that "let node = tree" creates just another "pointer" to the same Tree object. And we use that pointer to append new nodes. Without that we would just replace the same node.

Comment: Yes, node points to same object as tree. You could do that with the tree variable instead of the node variable, but I assume that you want to do someting with the tree variable later - therefore I kept the variable so you can access it for printing, saving or whatever after the loop. otherwise the tree variable would point to the latest child and not to the root node. @A.T.

Answer (score 1):

Just store previous child in a variable and append new node to it:

```
// declare new tree
myTree = new Tree('Diagrams')
let child = myTree;
for(let i = 1; i < 11; i++)
{
  child = child.createChildNode('A' + i);
}

myTree.print();
```